# SQL join multiple values

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

I've a question regarding a SQL query (with MariaDB).
I have several (simplified) table as below:

```
Players
+--------------+
| player       |
+--------------+
| RandomPlayer |
| ImaPlayer    |
+--------------+
```

```
Players_Actions
+--------------+------------------+
| player       | action           |
+--------------+------------------+
| RandomPlayer | Kill_10_Monsters |
| RandomPlayer | Kill_1_Boss      |
| RandomPlayer | Kill_5_Bosses    |
| ImaPlayer    | Kill_1_Boss      |
+--------------+------------------+
```

```
Achievements
+-------------+
| achievement |
+-------------+
| Adventurer  |
| Warrior     |
| Legend      |
+-------------+
```

```
Achievements_Actions
+-------------+------------------+
| achievement | action           |
+-------------+------------------+
| Adventurer  | Kill_10_Monsters |
| Adventurer  | Kill_1_Boss      |
| Warrior     | Kill_10_Monsters |
| Warrior     | Kill_5_Bosses    |
| Legend      | Kill_20_Monsters |
| Legend      | Kill_5_Bosses    |
+-------------+------------------+
```

An achievement is owned only if all actions are fulfilled.
I would like to retrieve player's achievements like this:

```
Players_Achievements
+--------------+-------------+------------------+
| player       | achievement | action           |
+--------------+-------------+------------------+
| RandomPlayer | Adventurer  | Kill_10_Monsters |
| RandomPlayer | Adventurer  | Kill_1_Boss      |
| RandomPlayer | Warrior     | Kill_10_Monsters |
| RandomPlayer | Warrior     | Kill_5_Bosses    |
+--------------+-------------+------------------+
```

I tried to use an `INNER JOIN` but the problem is, in this example, that I also get the "Legend" achievement for "RandomPlayer" and "Adventurer" for "ImaPlayer" (because of the "Kill_5_Bosses" and "Kill_1_Boss" rows).

```
SELECT Players_Actions.player, Achievements_Actions.achievement, Players_Actions.action
FROM Players_Actions
INNER JOIN Achievements_Actions
ON Achievements_Actions.action = Players_Actions.action;
```

But I'm getting below results:

```
+--------------+-------------+------------------+
| player       | achievement | action           |
+--------------+-------------+------------------+
| RandomPlayer | Adventurer  | Kill_10_Monsters |
| RandomPlayer | Adventurer  | Kill_1_Boss      |
| RandomPlayer | Warrior     | Kill_10_Monsters |
| RandomPlayer | Warrior     | Kill_5_Bosses    |
| RandomPlayer | Legend      | Kill_5_Bosses    |
| ImaPlayer    | Adventurer  | Kill_1_Boss      |
+--------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Two last records shouldn't be there.

An achievement can also have only one or more conditions, it's not always two like in my example.

I also tried things like `WITH RECURSIVE, IN,` etc. but I'm not sure which one to use and how.

Could you please help me to understand how I can do?

Comment: Please post what you tried to do

Comment: I can see what you want the result to look like, but I don't know what your actual result looks like. Post that and your SQL too for clarity.

Comment: Can you please confirm.  Do each of the tables have a unique auto-increment ID to handle the joins?  Or is your join based on the literal string matching.  Better to have auto-increment column so the "key id" is the join and not duplicating string messages between all the tables.  Please confirm.

Comment: Sorry, I added my attempt.
@DRapp In this example Primary Keys are the text, but of course in my real case they're not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, showing primary keys would always be preferred.  Please adjust my query to work based on those KEY IDs per your ACTUAL table structure.  I improvised but you will be able to obviously find and adjust.

If you wanted the HIGHEST Rank achieved, I would add a column to the Achievements table which would indicate which name context is the highest, thus Adventurer = 1, Warrior = 2, Legend = 3.  This way, you could get the MAX() qualified for all parts.  So, a player who has killed 5 bosses and 10 monsters qualifies as both adventurer and warrior, but the HIGHEST rank would be seen as warrior.  But that could be for a later expansion of your project.

Having said that, you need to get all qualified player actions to match all of the respective achievement's actions.  So, lets first get a pre-query.

```
select
        aa.AchievementID,
        count(*) as CntRequired
    from
        Achievements_Actions aa
    group by
        aa.AchievementID
```

This would result with below (parenthesis values are implied based on ID KEY of actual data)

```
AchievementID   CntRequired
1 (Adventurer)  2
2 (Warrior)     2
3 (Legend)      2
```

So if any player only qualified 1 of the 2, the would not qualify for that level of achievement.

Now, lets take each player and see what achievements were accomplished AS it
corresponds to the Achievements_Actions.

```
select
        pa.playerID,
        aa.AchievementID,
        count(*) as CntAchieved
    from
        Players_Actions pa
            JOIN Achievements_Actions aa
                on pa.AchieveActionID = aa.AchieveActionID
    group by
        pa.playerID,
        pa.AchievementID
```

This would result such as (similar, parenthesis player ID, achievment implied by KEY ID)

```
playerID           achievementID     CntAchieved
1 (RandomPlayer)   1 (Adventurer)    2
1 (RandomPlayer)   2 (Warrior)       2
2 (ImaPlayer)      1 (Adventurer)    1
```

So now, we can join these individual queries together based on those where the playerAchieved MATCHES those requiredParts per the achievement level. Once THAT JOIN qualifies, you can re-join back to the original achievment actions and players table to pull any other details not already shown in your abbreviated sample tables provided

```
select
        p.Player
        a.Achievement
        aa2.Action
    from
        ( select
                    aa.AchievementID,
                    count(*) as CntRequired
                from
                    Achievements_Actions aa
                group by
                    aa.AchievementID ) Qualified
            JOIN
            ( select
                    pa.playerID,
                    aa.AchievementID,
                    count(*) as CntAchieved
                from
                    Players_Actions pa
                        JOIN Achievements_Actions aa
                            on pa.AchieveActionID = aa.AchieveActionID
                group by
                    pa.playerID,
                    pa.AchievementID ) PerPlayer
                on Qualified.achievementID = PerPlayer.achievementID
                AND Qualified.CntRequired = PerPlayer.CntAchieved
            JOIN Players p
                on PerPlayer.PlayerID = p.playerID
            JOIN Achievements_Actions aa2
                on Qualified.achievementID = aa2.achievementID
            JOIN Achievements a
                on Qualified.achievementID = a.achievementID
```

Comment: Thank you, I still have some trouble to understand all the JOIN but I'll go into your solution in depth.

Comment: @Ksama, Try to run each individual query on its own merit to see and confirm the output of who / counts.  For example how many achievements to reach a particular level.  The next for each player to see how many they ACTUALLY qualify for.  Once both those are understood, look at the results of each and do the join on the per-achievement matching the required counts.  Only then will you get the details OF each achievement qualified for.

Comment: @Ksama, you probably still need to confirm the "ID" columns which were not included in your sample schema provided.